# submit data of select multiple in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, select

i have this form:

```
<form  id="filtri" action="ciao.php" method="post">
<select name="ruoli" id="ruoli" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" tabindex="-1"><option data-placeholder="true"----scegli----</option>
                    <option value="POR">POR</option>
                    <option value="LIB">LIB</option>
                    <option value="ADA">ADA</option>
                    <option value="DC">DC</option>
                    <option value="TS">TS</option>
                    <option value="ASA">ASA</option>
                    <option value="CDC">CDC</option>
                    <option value="CC">CC</option>
                    <option value="COC">COC</option>
                    <option value="ES">ES</option>
                    <option value="AS">AS</option>
                    <option value="ATS">ATS</option>
                    <option value="ED">ED</option>
                    <option value="AD">AD</option>
                    <option value="ATD">ATD</option>
                    <option value="AT">AT</option>
                    <option value="ATT">ATT</option>
                </select></form>
```

when i submit the value that can be multiple, method post or get sends me only the last value I had chosen. How can I get all the values?

Comment: is true to assign name to this select like: 'ruoli[]' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You should use ruoli[] as a name of your select. In that case, you will pass an array, named ruoli, of selected values.

```
$_POST['ruoli'] = array([0] => 'ADA', [1] => 'CDC', [2] => 'ATT')
```

the question is old, but still should be useful for others ;)